# Wrap found tag inside new tag in bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How to wrap a tag with new tag in bs4.

for example I have html like this.

```html
<html>
<body>
<p>Demo</p>
<p>world</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to convert it to this.

```html
<html>
<body>
<b><p>Demo</p></b>
<b> <p>world</p> </b>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is Exemplification.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """
        <html>
        <body>
        <p>Demo</p>
        <p>world</p>
        </body>
        </html>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for tag in soup.find_all('p'):
#    wrap tag with '<b>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Document](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#wrap):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """
        <html>
        <body>
        <p>Demo</p>
        <p>world</p>
        </body>
        </html>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for p in soup('p'):  # shortcut for soup.find_all('p')
    p.wrap(soup.new_tag("b"))
```

out:

```
<html>
<body>
<b><p>Demo</p></b>
<b><p>world</p></b>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Man. bs4 rocks